# How are requests and tests organized in postman?

Tags: automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am investigating Postman but I can't find an optimal way to organize the requests. Let me give an example:
Let's imagine I'm working on testing two microservices and my goal is to automate the tests and create a report that informs us of the outcome. Each microservice has 10 possible requests to perform (either get, post, etc.).

The ideal solution would be to have a collection which contains two folders (one per microservice) and that each folder has 10 requests; and to be able to run that collection from newman with a CSV/JSON data file, generating a final report (with tools like htmlextra).

The problem comes with data and iterations. Regarding the iterations, some of the requests like for example some 'GET' need only 1 execution but others like for example some 'POST' need several executions to check the status(if it returns a 200, a 400, etc.). Regarding the data, having 10 requests in the same collection, and some of the requests occupy quite a few columns of the csv, the data file becomes unreadable and hard to maintain.

So what I get when I run the collection is an unreadable data file and many iterations on requests that don't need them. As an alternative, I could create 1 collection for each request, and a data file for each collection but in that case I could not get a report as a whole when executing from newman, since to execute several collections I must execute several newman instructions, generating a report file for each one. So I would get 20 html file as report, 1 for each request(also not readable).

Sorry if I am pointing in the wrong direction as I have no experience with the tool.
On the web I only see examples of reports and basic collections, but I'm left wanting to see something more 'real'.

Thanks a lot!!!

Summary of my notes:

- Only 1 data file can be assigned to the collection runner.
- There are many requests which have a lot of data, about 10 columns, so if we have one data file for several, it becomes unreadable. Ideally 1 file for each request.
- This forces us to create a collection for each request, since only 1 file per collection is feasible.
- Newman can only run 1 collection per command, if you want to launch more, you have to duplicate instruction. This forces to create a report per collection. If we have 1 collection per request, we would have 1 report for each one instead of a report with the status of all the requests, so it loses the sense.

Comment: I think it's better if you remove data files, then go with either way: 1. convert each record of data file to a separate request or 2. put data in pre-request then use postman.setNextRequest() to create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem in this way:

1. The data file is stored for a few data sets (in my case - test cases). I created an additional column in the data file with the variable dId to uniquely identify and manage each dataset.
2. in the postman in the beginning collection create a new request (do nothing) and name it Setup.
3. Setup -> Test tab:

   ```
     switch (data.dId) {
    case (101):
        postman.setNextRequest('request_101');
        break;
    case (102):
        postman.setNextRequest('request_102');
        break;
    case (103):
        postman.setNextRequest('request_103');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('No value found');
   ```

   }
4. In other requests in the collection set what do you want to happen after execution by postman.setNextRequest(_reqName); //or postman.setNextRequest(null);

Ex.:
[flow control through an additional setup request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BxNI.png)

It can be strange, but it works :)